# お世話になってます vs お疲れ様です

Tags: word-choice, business-japanese

I work in Company A, and mailing within Company A usually starts with:

> 〇〇さん、
>
> お疲れ様です、〇〇です。

We have a joint dev team with Company B, and mailing to Company B starts with:

> 〇〇さん　*or*　〇〇会社ＸＸ事業担当者様
>
> いつもお世話になっております、〇〇です。　*or*　〇〇会社の〇〇と申します。

An employee of Company C is on loan to our Company A. Which greeting should I use when mailing to Company C employee?

Comment: `An employee of Company C is on loan to our Company A.` <- その社員はC社からA社に**派遣**されている (= **出向**している) ってことですよね？ And, by `when mailing to Company C employee,` you mean when you send an email to **the** Company C employee who currently works with you in Company A, right?

Comment: @Shoko I'm not really sure if 派遣 (dispatch worker?) is the proper way to describe it. But yes, Company C's employee works at Company A and can be seen as officially representing us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are possible. To put it simply, お疲れさまです looks less respectful but more friendly, whereas お世話になっております looks more formal and respectful. Which to use would depend on your character/preference, the custom of your company, and the actual relationship between you and the person in Company C. Which describes the person C better, your colleague, or your client?

If you're unsure, it's always safe to get away with お世話になっております.

Comment: I see. I usually piggyback off the style my co-workers use, but in the case of Company C's employee, some use the former and some use the latter.

Answer (score 1):

I will add an answer that I hope will be beneficial.

Both words do not have the same meaning.

お世話になっております

is something you say in place of where you would use “thanks for always taking care of me, we are indebted to you..ect..”

お疲れ様です

is used to basically say “good job, you worked hard ect..” and is generally a greeting you use with co-workers when they are leaving.

The main thing to keep in mind with the usages is the term Uchi and Soto. This means within and outside of. People within your group “uchi” (co-workers) you will use less formal language and also say お疲れ様です at the end of the day. Those  who may work for a different company that you are doing business with are “soto” (those outside your group /non-co-workers ect…) you will say お世話になっております usually when you see them (more likely いつもおせわになっとります).

I have been yelled at a few times for not understanding uchi and soto properly. Such as talking about a co-worker to someone outside the company and adding -san when I should have used their name without the honorific as they are part of my group.

Answer (score 0):

The company/employee is not yours, it is almost always better to write/print as

> 〇〇会社ＸＸ事業担当者様
>
> 〇〇会社ＸＸ事業御中　*お名前* 様 (if you know who)
>
> いつもお世話になっております、<s>〇〇です</s>

Your name should be at the end of the letter.

On the contrary, talk on the phone or in a meeting, introduce first.

> A社の*Your_name*と申します、いつもお世話になっております

Comment: Been here 4 months and have never seen anyone write it that way...

Comment: Formal business letters are like this. http://b-writing.com/shagai_bunsho/owabi/shohin_mino.html

Answer (score 0):

The employee of Company C is on loan to your Company A, which means the employee is currently working with you for Company A, then I think you'd usually treat them as one of your colleagues. (I believe that's how we normally treat 派遣/出向社員.) Therefore I suggest you use the former format, which starts with 「〇〇さん、お疲れ様です、〇〇です。」